# I am having difficult getting my loop to work

Tags: java, loops

I am having difficulty getting a loop to work. The loop should have an out if the user types "Quit" or "quit" in the beginning, but continue processing if Quit is not entered.

I have tried a do loop however since that will run the loop once it does not work with the parameters given. I also cannot get an if/else statement to work at all. I am using Eclipse to code/compile as directed by my professor.

Here is the current snippet I have:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan= new Scanner (System.in);
    String fullName;
    int total= 0;
        System.out.print("Please enter your full name: ");
        fullName= scan.nextLine(); //Scans user input for name
        int count= fullName.length()-1;//Evaluates the length of the user's name
        while (fullName.equalsIgnoreCase("Quit || quit")) 
        {   
        System.out.println("Thank you for using the system. Come back soon.");
        }
        {   
            System.out.println("Please enter "+count+" numbers and the total will be calculated\n");
                    for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
                    int userEnteredNum= scan.nextInt();
                    total += userEnteredNum;
                }
            System.out.println("Good day, "+ fullName+ "! You have entered "+
            count+ " numbers.\nThe total of all the numbers is "+ total);
        }
        while (fullName.equalsIgnoreCase("Quit || quit")); 
}
```

}

If the user types quit, it should display a thank you message and not continue. If the user does not type quit, the program should proceed and ask for the user to enter numbers based on the character length of their name, and add them up, then repeat until the user types quit.

With the current version I have, this is what happens:

"Please enter your full name: Quit
Please enter 3 numbers and the total will be calculated"

or "Please enter your full name: Jane Lane
Please enter 8 numbers and the total will be calculated

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
Good day, Jane Lane! You have entered 8 numbers.
The total of all the numbers is 36"

Comment: Checking for `"Quit || quit"` means that user literally enters that string, not `"Quit"` or `"quit"`.

Comment: And if you're using `equalsIgnoreCase` you don't have to test for both "Quit" and "quit".

Comment: Why the extra `while` loop at the bottom?

Comment: Also, you never update `fullName` in your loops... so when entered they don't terminate.

Comment: I think your first `while` should be an `if`, and there should be an `else` before the last code block.

Answer (score 0):

The comment and answer you got are right, having the condition `fullName.equalsIgnoreCase("Quit  || quit")` literally just enters if you write Quit || quit.
If using equalsIgnoreCase either Quit or quit will do, if you want to use `||` you could use `fullName.equals("Quit") || fullName.equals("quit")`. The logic operator must be outside the string to compare

Answer (score 0):

you are not quitting the program when quit string occurs - Try this

```
if (fullName.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) 
{   
    System.out.println("Thank you for using the system. Come back soon.");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            String fullName;
            int total = 0;
            System.out.print("Please enter your full name: ");
            fullName = scan.nextLine(); //Scans user input for name
            int count = fullName.length() - 1;//Evaluates the length of the user's name
            if (fullName.equalsIgnoreCase("Quit")) {
                System.out.println("Thank you for using the system. Come back soon.");
                return;
            }
            System.out.println("Please enter " + count + " numbers and the total will be calculated\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                int userEnteredNum = scan.nextInt();
                total += userEnteredNum;
            }
            System.out.println("Good day, " + fullName + "! You have entered " +
                    count + " numbers.\nThe total of all the numbers is " + total);
        }
    }
```